# How to control fleas in the garden?

Tags: pest-control

Our garden seem to have some fleas (see pictures here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95248/insect-identification-question-is-this-a-flea-if-yes-what-kind). They sometimes get inside the house when we get inside after working in the garden. How can we control/get rid of the fleas?

Comment: Do you have pets? If so, are they protected from fleas via "flea dope" and do they get on your bed?

Comment: No. Ours is a pet free household.